# How to increase tfm_size while running tftopl?

Tags: miktex

I am trying to convert `mt2mit.tfm` in the MathTime Pro 2 Lite package to a property list. This file is rather large (more than 30 KB).

Running `tftopl mt2mit.tfm mt2mit.pl` I got the message `The file is bigger than I can handle!`

How can I increase `tfm_size` from `30000` (29.296875 KB) to a larger number? I am using MiKTeX 2.9.6809 on Windows 8.

Comment: No problem with TeX Live.

Comment: works ok in texlive but fails in miktex. I don't see a configuration option, probably you will have to make a feature request.

Comment: @egreg Strange indeed. The source code in TeX Live is `@!tfm_size=30000; {maximum length of |tfm| data, in bytes}` for `tftopl`, which means it should not work with TeX Live either, but it worked…

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/373